# angularjs with ng-grid master detail paradigm that has multi-select with modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, ng-grid

Apologies for the confusing title.  So I have multi-select + ng-grid working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aMs7dRsEhqB71oV4ldi8?p=preview) .

For anyone who isn't sure what the master/detail paradigm is.  I select a row from my grid and expose all of its properties in some fashion for a complete view of the row from my grid (master being inside the grid, details being the object properties)

I want it to do something like [image: this]

But I cannot seem to figure out how to get this type of detail view to occur.  I presume I need to have some type of `emit/broadcast/on` type set of events.  So again the question is how do I do the master/detail view with a modal and multiple selections in angularjs + ng-grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you want to create the modal, but there are plenty of choices out there.  One being the [angular bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) modal.

That aside, in terms of getting data out of `ng-grid`, you can use the `afterSelectionChange` grid option to delegate to a function that will fire after a selection has been made.

[This fork of your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Lui5X?p=preview) demonstrates using `afterSelectionChange`.

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
  multiSelect: true,
  afterSelectionChange: function() {

    $scope.details = $scope.mySelections;
  }
};

$scope.details = null;
```

You can then `ng-repeat` the results:

```
<button ng-click="show = !show">Show/Hide Details</button>
<div class="selectedItems" ng-show="show">
  You have selected:<br/><br/>
  <div ng-repeat="detail in details">
    name: {{ detail.name }}<br/>
    age: {{ detail.age }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.  Let me know if there is something I missed.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I integrated angular bootstrap modal into [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VPNN9c?p=preview).

It might also help to look at an example of the angular bootstrap modal without `ng-grid`.  You can find that [here in this modal plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8JtLdU?p=preview).

Comment: so what i would anticipate to happen is i would select multiple rows, for instance the first two.  Then I would be able to click something that would give me a modal showing everything i have selected.

Comment: Sounds fine, should I update my plunker to show something like this?  In the simple case, I would use a `button` with an `ng-click` to show.  And then show the same `div`. I'll update it.

Comment: yes much closer :) .  The last piece I need is for that to render inside a modal after button click.  So the reasoning behind it is I want the users to know which subset of data they are using.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Alright, see the latest EDIT. I integrated angular bootstrap into the plunker.  This is pretty rough, but should give you an idea of how to wire it together.